# how show error if no args was set in console trying execute python script

Tags: python, getopt

I need to write python script which need command arguments for executing. I have such code:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"htt:tf:d:",["from=","to=","on="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-h':
        print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
        sys.exit()
    # elif opt
    elif opt in ("-f", "--from"):
        fromTime = arg
    elif opt in ("-t", "--to"):
        toTime = arg
    elif opt in ("-d", "--on"):
        onDate = arg
```

But than I run my script without any arguments it just do nothing. How can I add some check like if no args are specified the error message should be shown in the console (or help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no arguments set, `opts` will be an empty list:

```
if not opts:
    print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
    sys.exit(2)
```

You should really consider using the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead, which lets you specify that some command line options are mandatory.

Comment: I tried as you write but result is the same, no message appears. It is hard to use argparse because it is not default in python 2.5, and my script could be used for different environments, and it is a headache to install everythere this module

Comment: @khris: then `opts` is *not* empty. I tested this just now; `opts` is an list if no command-line switches have been used.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I put that part of code in the wrong place, it works now. Thank you